# PyQtGraph: GUI unresponsive during only one process

Tags: pyqt, pyqtgraph

I'm writing a GUI for a video camera that can basically run in two modes that I call liveview and recordview. The only difference being that I'm recording in the latter and only viewing in the former.

In liveview mode the image gets updated properly. I've set a button that triggers recordview but during this acquisition the GUI gets unresponsive and the image doesn't get updated. Let me show you the relevant parts of the code:

```
import numpy as np
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
import pyqtgraph as pg
from lantz.drivers.andor.ccd import CCD

app = QtGui.QApplication([])

def updateview():     # <-- this works OK
    global img, andor
    img.setImage(andor.most_recent_image16(andor.detector_shape),
                 autoLevels=False)

def liveview():
    """ Image live view when not recording
    """
    global andor, img, viewtimer

    andor.acquisition_mode = 'Run till abort'
    andor.start_acquisition()
    viewtimer.start(0)

def UpdateWhileRec():
    global stack, andor, img, n, ishape

    j = 0
    while j < n:
        if andor.n_images_acquired > j:

            # Data saving    <-- this part (and the whole while-loop) works OK
            i, j = andor.new_images_index
            stack[i - 1:j] = andor.images16(i, j, ishape, 1, n)

            # Image updating <-- this doesn't work
            img.setImage(stack[j - 1], autoLevels=False)

    liveview()   # After recording, it goes back to liveview mode

def record(n):
    """ Record an n-frames acquisition
    """
    global andor, ishape, viewtimer, img, stack, rectimer

    andor.acquisition_mode = 'Kinetics'
    andor.set_n_kinetics(n)
    andor.start_acquisition()

    # Stop the QTimer that updates the image with incoming data from the
    # 'Run till abort' acquisition mode.
    viewtimer.stop()
    QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(1, UpdateWhileRec)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    with CCD() as andor:

        win = QtGui.QWidget()
        rec = QtGui.QPushButton('REC')
        imagewidget = pg.GraphicsLayoutWidget()
        p1 = imagewidget.addPlot()
        img = pg.ImageItem()
        p1.addItem(img)

        layout = QtGui.QGridLayout()
        win.setLayout(layout)
        layout.addWidget(rec, 2, 0)
        layout.addWidget(imagewidget, 1, 2, 3, 1)

        win.show()

        viewtimer = QtCore.QTimer()
        viewtimer.timeout.connect(updateview)

        # Record routine
        n = 100
        newimage = np.zeros(ishape)
        stack = np.zeros((n, ishape[0], ishape[1]))
        rec.pressed.connect(lambda: record(n))

        liveview()

        app.exec_()
        viewtimer.stop()
```

As you see `UpdateWhileRec` runs only once per acquisition while `updateview` runs until `viewtimer.stop()` is called.

I'm new to PyQt and PyQtGraph so regardless of the particular way of solving my present issue, there's probably a better way to do everything else. If that's the case please tell me!

thanks in advanced

Comment: Have you tested whether the record-function is completely executed when you hit the 'rec' button? My guess would be that `start_acquisition` might by busy waiting for input/events etc...

Comment: Yes, I tested it thoroughly but I erased all the prints before posting my question here :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem stems from the fact that you need to return control to the Qt event loop for it to redraw the picture. Since you remain in the `UpdateWhileRec` callback while waiting for the next image to be acquired, Qt never gets a chance to draw the image. It only gets the chance once you exit the function `UpdateWhileRec`.

I would suggest the following changes.

Then instead of your while loop in `UpdateWhileRec`, have a QTimer that periodically calls the contents of your current while loop (i would probably suggest a singleshot timer). This ensures control will be returned to Qt so it can draw the image before checking for a new one.

So something like:

```
def UpdateWhileRec():
    # Note, j should be initialised to 0 in the record function now
    global stack, andor, img, n, j, ishape 


    if andor.n_images_acquired > j:    
        # Data saving    <-- this part (and the whole while-loop) works OK
        i, j = andor.new_images_index
        stack[i - 1:j] = andor.images16(i, j, ishape, 1, n)

        # Image updating <-- this should now work
        img.setImage(stack[j - 1], autoLevels=False)

    if j < n:
        QTimer.singleShot(0, UpdateWhileRec)
    else:
        liveview()   # After recording, it goes back to liveview mode
```

Note, you should probably put functions and variables in a class, and create an instance of the class (an object). That way you don't have to call `global` everywhere and things are more encapsulated.

Ultimately, you may want to look into whether your andor library supports registering a function to be called when a new image is available (a callback) which would save you doing this constant polling and/or acquiring the images in a thread and posting them back to the GUI thread to be drawn. But one step at a time!

Comment: Thanks man, it works. So if I understand correctly, everytime the QTimer is called, the application redraws the GUI? Thanks for the suggestions as well

Comment: Sort of. Qt has an event queue, which it processes one at a time. The first time you call `QTimer.singleShot` an entry is added to this queue. When it gets to the entry, it executes the specified function. Your function runs, and when you update the image, an entry is placed in Qt's queue to redraw it. Then you call QTimer.singleShot again, which adds another item to the queue. When your function has finished running, Qt processes it's queue, first it redraws the image, then it processes the timer and calls your function. Make sense?

Comment: There will also be other things in the event queue, like mouse move events, window move events, etc. None of these can be processed while the program is still in the middle of executing your function. By breaking up your function into multiple calls, you give Qt a chance to do all the other things it needs to! As a simple test, try calling `time.sleep(5)` in a function executed by a single shot timer. You should find the GUI unresponsive (try moving the window) for those 5 seconds because Qt doesn't get to process it's event queue!

Comment: Thanks, now it makes perfect sense!